# How to copy a function and set a default parameter in Python?

Tags: python, methods

Let's say I have the following definition:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x + y
```

And then I want to have a copy of the function `foo` (let's call it `bar`), where `x` is always equal to `0`.

i.e. `bar(4)` would return `4`.

How can I do this in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
bar = lambda y: foo (0, y)
```

If you want to delete foo, as user pointed out, you can use:

```
def foo (x, y): return x + y

bar = (lambda f: lambda y: f (0, y) ) (foo)
print (bar (4) )
del foo
print (bar (4) )
```

Answer (score 6):

[`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is an efficient way to do this:

```
import functools
bar = functools.partial(foo, 0)
bar(4) == 4
```

It also lets you supply a function that isn't bound to a variable, or rebind the variable after creating the `partial` object, which can prevent errors with loops or comprehensions:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul
funcs = [lambda x: foo(3, x) for foo in add, sub, mul]
funcs[0](3) == 9 # Not 6!

funcs = [functools.partial(foo, 3) for foo in add, sub, mul]
funcs[0](3) == 6 # Works!
```